# What is a proper way of using next-intl in a server component that is inside of a client component?

Tags: react-hooks, internationalization, next.js13, next-intl

I'm working on a project that uses next-intl for internationalization. I have both client and server components. This is how the simplified project structure look like:

```bash
|_ app
   |_ [locale]
      |_ page.js (SSR)
|_ components
   |_ Contact.jsx (SSR)
   |_ Menu.jsx (CSR)
```

where SSR is server-side rendered component and CSR is client-side rendered component.

In every component I have to use internationalized text depending on chosen language, moreover I use `Contact` component both in `page.js` and `Menu.jsx`.

I've tried putting `useTranslations` hook from next-intl in every component and in `page.js`, it works well, however when I use `useTranslations` in server-side component that is inside client-side component (`Contact.jsx` in `Menu.jsx` in this case) `useTranslations` doesn't work and text is not loading at all.

I've read in the documentation that it is preferred to get text via `useTranslations` in server-side component and pass it via props to client-side component, however it messes up my code. What's the better way of doing it?

Comment: what's next-intl version do you use? check package.json